# How to grab Client System IP Address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to grab/track IP Address of Client machine(requesting machine or user's computer) not Server machine.

I have put following code to grab/track IP Address of Client machine that it's working.

```
Request.ServerVariables.Get("REMOTE_HOST");
```

But it's working on those system in which internet modem directly connected with pc

And I need to work on those systems too in which internet modem isn't directly connected with pc (connected via router).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP request header so you can get the IP addresses of the firewalls and routers along the chain of the request? As other answers have stated you won't be able to get access to the original client's internal IP address, but you should be able to get the IP address of the first public-facing router their request emanated from.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get the internal address of the client. That's what [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and [firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29) are for. I know this is a disappointing answer, but what you're asking simply isn't possible in most contexts.

The only exception is if you control both the client machine and the server. For example, a corporate environment. Then you could write some tools that would provide that information to the server. Obviously, asking random people that visit your website to install your tools on their machine isn't really a feasible option.

It might help your question if you provide more detail about your environment and *why* you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that. Also, knowing the internal network IP address is not going to help you access it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP' OR 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' which will return you list of comma separated IP

```
i.e.    Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

Thanks
Suresh